# Unable to display data extracted from a list stored in SQLIte database

Tags: android, sqlite

I need to display the data name, mobile, and email by clicking on an email in a list from the SQLite database.

**This is my listener:**

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
       email= (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
       Intent intent = new 
              Intent(UserListActivity.this,DisplayActivity.class);
       intent.putExtra("Login_Info"," "+email);
       startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

**DisplayActivity.java:**

```
public class DisplayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView listView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);
    String login_info = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Login_Info");
    DBHelper db = new DBHelper(DisplayActivity.this);
    ArrayList<String> displayUsersData = db.displayUsersData(login_info);
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(DisplayActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,displayUsersData);
    listView = findViewById(R.id.listview_display);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
```

**This is the method displayUsersData(email):**

```
public ArrayList<String> displayUsersData(String email){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" where "+COL_EMAIL+"='"+email+"'",null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String emailId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_EMAIL));
    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_NAME));
    String mobile = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_MOBILE));
    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
    data.add(emailId);
    data.add(name);
    data.add(mobile);
    return data;

}
```

Comment: Please explain more your problem and why you are adding " " as prefix in email string on click of List item?. try to use latest component RecycleView instead of ListView.

Comment: This is for a Login and Signup Application. When the user keys in the details(name, email, mobile, password), it gets stored in the SQLite database. And when I will view the user's list(a list of registered emails), by clicking on the email, I should be able to view user data(name, email, and mobile).